# Create trigger to insert rows from one table to another with sum operation (group by)

Tags: mysql, trigger

I have two tables in my database **traffic_shift** and **traffic_daily**. With following columns.

Table **traffic_shift** :-

```
day     month    year    toll_id    shift    car_single    car_return 
 1       9        2016    1          1        10            5
 1       9        2016    1          2        100           50
 1       9        2016    1          3        200           100

 1       9        2016    2          1        15            20
 1       9        2016    2          2        30            40
 1       9        2016    2          3        45            60

 2       9        2016    1          1        12            6
 2       9        2016    1          2        24            12
 2       9        2016    1          3        36            18

 2       9        2016    2          1        18            9
 2       9        2016    2          2        36            18
 2       9        2016    2          3        54            27
```

**traffic_daily** table will be like this,

Table **traffic_daily**

```
day     month    year    toll_id    car_single    car_return 
 1       9       2016     1          310          155
 1       9       2016     2          90           120
 2       9       2016     1          60           30
 2       9       2016     2          108          54
```

As you can see there are 3 shift in a day for any toll. So the functioning of the trigger should be :

it should sum up the **car_single** and **car_return**, date wise for each toll and should insert into the table **traffic_daily** as shown in above table.

This is what I have so far:

```
DROP TRIGGER after_insert_shift;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `test`.`after_insert_shift` 
AFTER INSERT ON `test`.`shift`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
INSERT INTO daily   
SET
`day` = new.day,
`month` = new.month,
`year`= new.year,
toll_id = new.toll_id,
car_single = SELECT SUM(car_single) 
    WHERE daily.day = new.day , daily.month = new.month, daily.year = new.month ,
    daily.toll_id = new.toll_id FROM shift GROUP BY 
    shift.day,shift.month,shift.year,shift.toll_id;

car_return = SELECT SUM(car_return) WHERE daily.day = new.day , 
    daily.month = new.month, daily.year = new.month , 
    daily.toll_id = new.toll_id FROM shift GROUP BY
    shift.day,shift.month,shift.year,shift.toll_id;


END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend against using a trigger as a solution.  In general, if you are going to INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE with a trigger, you will can experience problems with concurrency, data quality, and maintainability.  I recommend you read this [Ask TOM article](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/the-trouble-with-triggers). Consider the following scenarios:

- One more rows in the traffic_shift table are updated.  You will need another trigger as others have pointed out.
- Rows are deleted from  the traffic_shift table.  Do you delete the data in traffic_daily?  What if only a shift is removed?  Another trigger with even more logic.
- Inserts into the traffic_shift table could happen concurrently.  Unless you lock the traffic_daily table, one of the triggers will fail.

At this point, you are duplicating some of the functionality of the underlying DBMS in your trigger.  Plus you could have 3 triggers that are manipulating data behind the scenes.  I would be willing to bet money that this solution will be annoying to maintain.  Aside from those concerns, traffic_daily would contain incorrect data if you have less than 3 shifts of data.

If you want to go ahead with a trigger based approach, [this Ask TOM article](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::p11_question_id:4233459000346171405) has an Oracle based solution that is similar to your design and I think it can be adapted to MySQL.  What I like about this approach, is that the trigger can be written to only update traffic_daily only if the day exists in traffic_daily.  That would prevent incomplete data from going into traffic_daily.   Also, because the trigger is not inserting a row, you do not need to worry about concurrency.  Even if two triggers update simultaneously, they will be updating with the same data (if you enforce a 3 shifts requirement).

The content of your traffic_daily table is derived from the traffic_shift table.  When I see the word "derived" my first thought is to implement that as a view.  A view will keep traffic_daily in sync with the underlying without needing a trigger.  There are two factors that you need to be evaluated for a view-based solution:

- Will data from the traffic_shift table be archived or purged?
- What is the size and rate of growth of the traffic_shift table?

### No Archive/Purge of traffic_shift

You can implement traffic_daily as a view.  The type of view will depend on the rate of growth.

### Archive/Purge of traffic_shift

Assuming you  want to retain the summary data in traffic_daily, one solution would be to have a table containing the traffic_daily rows of data that has been archived.  You then have a view with the current traffic_daily data.  If you want, you can have a view that is the union of the archived traffic_daily and current traffic_daily.

### Small traffic_shift size

If you have on the order of 100 or less unique toll_ids, the traffic_shift table will be 100,000 rows/year or less.  At that size, a regular view would probably work in terms of performance.

### Large traffic_shift size

If you have on the order of 1000 or more unique toll_ids, the traffic_shift table may be getting large enough to slow a view down (depending on the size of the database server).  At that scale, a materialized view would probably be a better solution.
Materialized views do not exist in all versions of MySQL, but you can read more in the [MySQL version 8.0 documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-table-optimization.html).

### Other Thoughts

The view can enforce the requirement that there are 3 shifts of data for each toll_id.  If you want to view incomplete sets of data, you could have a column in the view with the number of shifts in the sum.  The view solution keeps the business requirements for traffic_daily in one place rather than spread out over multiple triggers.

Answer (score 0):

First observation, `FROM` is usually before `WHERE`, i.e.

```
car_single = SELECT SUM(car_single) FROM shift WHERE ...
```

Second observation, `INSERT`normally have the form:

```
INSERT INTO daily (day, month, ... ) 
VALUES (...)
```

These are the syntactical errors I find in your trigger. Logically I think there is more to do. Your trigger will insert a new row into daily every time a new row is inserted into shift, from your description that does not sound right. Here's what I would try to do (only a sketch).

```
CREATE TRIGGER `test`.`after_insert_shift` 
AFTER INSERT ON `test`.`shift`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    UPDATE daily SET (car_single, car_return) = (
        SELECT SUM(car_single), SUM(car_return)
        FROM shift
        WHERE day = new.day 
          AND daily.month = new.month
          AND daily.year = new.year 
          AND ...
    )
    WHERE daily.month = new.month
      AND daily.year = new.year
      AND ...  

    -- Check if number of rows updated = 0, if so insert a new row
    SELECT ROW_COUNT() INTO N;
    IF N = 0 THEN
        INSERT INTO daily (c1, c2, c3, ...)
        SELECT ...
```

Don't know if that's your problem, but I would start there.

Comment: First of all syntactical errors was mistake that i made while writing the question. And you got it right, when ran my query it was creating a new row every time when there was a insert into **daily** table.

Answer (score 0):

Use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` with a suitable unique (or primary) key.  That will create a new row when necessary, otherwise increment the existing row.

A tip:  Do not split dates into 3 columns; instead use the `DATE` datatype.

Answer (score 0):

No SUM'ing required here - use the Triggers keep things up to date as you go along.

Create Insert and Update Triggers on traffic_shift to update traffic_daily with the values given to the trigger:

```
update daily set 
  car_return = car_return + new.car_return - old.car_return 
, car_single = car_single + new.car_single - old.car_single 
where day   = new.day 
  and month = new.month
  and year  = new.year ;
```

For the Insert Trigger, lose the references to "old.".

If you need a Delete Trigger as well, lose the references to "new.".

And, obviously, all three Triggers have to deal with needing to create a new record in traffic_daily.   :-)